# Environment variable in Windows - %JAVA_HOME% = C:\Program\Java\jdk1.8.0_271 instead of C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

In Windows 10, I set some system environment variables via the System Properties window:

[image: System Environment Variables]

However, when I run `set` from the Command Prompt, I see "Program" in the path for JAVA_1_8_HOME and JAVA_HOME, rather than "Program Files" as is in JAVA_17_HOME and JDK_HOME:

```
JAVA_17_HOME=C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk17.0.8_8
JAVA_1_8_HOME=C:\Program\Java\jdk1.8.0_271
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program\Java\jdk1.8.0_271
JDK_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271
```

And, yes, `echo` shows the same:

```
>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program\Java\jdk1.8.0_271
```

Why is there this inconsistency?  I even copy the value from JDK_HOME and pasted into JAVA_HOME in case there were some weird hidden characters or something.  Is there something else in Windows that could be overriding the setting from the System Properties?